# Finding one-to-one, one-to-many, and many-to-one relationships between columns

Tags: r, dplyr

Consider the following data frame:

```
 first_name last_name
1         Al     Smith
2         Al     Jones
3       Jeff  Thompson
4      Scott  Thompson
5      Terry    Dactil
6       Pete       Zah

data <- data.frame(first_name=c("Al","Al","Jeff","Scott","Terry","Pete"),
                   last_name=c("Smith","Jones","Thompson","Thompson","Dactil","Zah"))
```

In this data frame, there are three ways that first_name is related to last_name:

- One to one (i.e. there is a unique relationship between first_name
  and last_name)
- One to many (i.e. one first_name points to multiple
  last_name values)
- Many to one (i.e. multiple first_name values point
     to one last_name)

I want to be able to quickly identify each of the three cases and output them to a data frame. So, the resulting data frames would be:

One to one

```
  first_name last_name
1      Terry    Dactil
2       Pete       Zah
```

One to many

```
  first_name last_name
1         Al     Smith
2         Al     Jones
```

Many to one

```
   first_name last_name
1       Jeff  Thompson
2      Scott  Thompson
```

I would like to do this within the dplyr package.

Comment: You want the `duplicated()` function

Comment: [Here](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Finding_and_removing_duplicate_records/) is some example code using `duplicated()`, but I think it would be cool if you could give us something specific here, @RichardScriven. I am not grokking it to solve this problem. ty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, you can check if a value is duplicated using the `duplicated` function (as mentioned by @RichardScriven in a comment on your question). However, by default this function doesn't mark the first instance of an element that appears multiple times as duplicated:

```
duplicated(c(1, 1, 1, 2))
# [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Since you also want to pick up these cases, you generally would want to run `duplicated` on each vector twice, once forward and once backwards:

```
duplicated(c(1, 1, 1, 2)) | duplicated(c(1, 1, 1, 2), fromLast=TRUE)
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

I find this to be a lot of typing, so I'll define a helper function that checks if an element appears more than once:

```
d <- function(x) duplicated(x) | duplicated(x, fromLast=TRUE)
```

Now the logic you want is all simple one-liners:

```
# One to one
data[!d(data$first_name) & !d(data$last_name),]
#   first_name last_name
# 5      Terry    Dactil
# 6       Pete       Zah

# One to many
data[d(data$first_name) & !d(data$last_name),]
#   first_name last_name
# 1         Al     Smith
# 2         Al     Jones

# Many to one
data[!d(data$first_name) & d(data$last_name),]
#   first_name last_name
# 3       Jeff  Thompson
# 4      Scott  Thompson
```

Note that you could also define `d` without the help of `duplicated` using the `table` function:

```
d <- function(x) table(x)[x] > 1
```

While this alternate definition is slightly more succinct, I also find it less readable.

Comment: I kinda wish my name was Terry Dactil now

Comment: @RichardScriven I would have expected "Terry Dactyl", but yeah that would be a great conversation starter!

Comment: is r won't consider `function(x) duplicated(x)` and `duplicated(x, fromLast=TRUE)` as two separate parts?

Comment: @AvinashRaj The function body will be all of `duplicated(x) | duplicated(x, fromLast=TRUE)`, just like in the second function the body will be all of `table(x)[x] > 1`. When in doubt you can add `{` and `}` to enclose the body.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a pure dplyr approach, using the same logic as *josliber*, by adding new count columns for each variable:

```
data <- data %>% 
  add_count(first_name, name="first_name_n") %>%
  add_count(last_name, name="last_name_n")

# one-to-one
data %>% filter(first_name_n == 1 & last_name_n == 1)

# one-to-many
data %>% filter(first_name_n == 1 & last_name_n > 1)

# many-to-one
data %>% filter(first_name_n > 1 & last_name_n == 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using @josliber's suggested method, I constructed a function that takes two vectors and returns their relationship type:

```
relationship_type <- function(x1, x2, na.rm = FALSE) {

  df <- tibble(x1 = x1, x2 = x2)

  if (na.rm) {
    df <- df %>%
      drop_na()
  }

  res <- c()

  counts <- df %>%
    count(x1, x2) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    select(-n) %>%
    count(x1, x2)

  if (any(is.na(counts$x2))) {
    res <- c(res, "one to zero")
  }

  if (any(is.na(counts$x1))) {
    res <- c(res, "zero to one")
  }

  if (anyDuplicated(counts$x1) == 0 & anyDuplicated(counts$x2) == 0) {
    res <- c(res, "one to one")
  }

  if (anyDuplicated(counts$x1) > 0 & anyDuplicated(counts$x2) == 0) {
    res <- c(res, "one to many")
  }

  if (anyDuplicated(counts$x1) == 0 & anyDuplicated(counts$x2) > 0) {
    res <- c(res, "many to one")
  }

  if (anyDuplicated(counts$x1) > 0 & anyDuplicated(counts$x2) > 0) {
    res <- c(res, "many to many")
  }

  res
}
```

The one to zero will tell you if some entries in one vector are mapped to no entries in another. You can write another wrapper over this function that takes in a dataframe and a pair of column names and passe you back the results.

Answer (score 0):

In case the data contains repeated items, any solution using the `duplicated` function would not work.

For example:

```
data1 = data.frame(first_name=c("Al","Al","Jeff","Scott","Terry","Pete", "Jeff","Scott","Terry","Pete"),
                   last_name=c("Smith","Jones","Thompson","Thompson","Dactil","Zah", "Smith","Jones", "Dactil","Zah"))
```

Here's a solution using `data.table` which works on both the above case as well as OP's original data:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data1)

# One to one
temp1 = data1[ , uniqueN(last_name), by = 'first_name'][V1 == 1]
temp2 = data1[ , uniqueN(first_name), by = 'last_name'][V1 == 1]
data1[first_name %in% temp1$first_name & last_name %in% temp2$last_name]

#    first_name last_name
# 1:      Terry    Dactil
# 2:       Pete       Zah
# 3:      Terry    Dactil
# 4:       Pete       Zah


# One to many
temp3 = data1[ , uniqueN(last_name), by = 'first_name'][V1 > 1]
data1[first_name %in% temp3$first_name][order(first_name)]

#    first_name last_name
# 1:         Al     Smith
# 2:         Al     Jones
# 3:       Jeff  Thompson
# 4:       Jeff     Smith
# 5:      Scott  Thompson
# 6:      Scott     Jones


# Many to one
temp4 = data1[ , uniqueN(first_name), by = 'last_name'][V1 > 1]
data1[last_name %in% temp4$last_name][order(last_name)]

#    first_name last_name
# 1:         Al     Jones
# 2:      Scott     Jones
# 3:         Al     Smith
# 4:       Jeff     Smith
# 5:       Jeff  Thompson
# 6:      Scott  Thompson
```